# How do I get the lower 8 bits of an int?

Tags: c

Lets say I have an int variable n = 8. On most machines this will be a 32 bit value. How can I only get the lower 8 bits (lowest byte) of this in binary? Also how can I access each bit to find out what it is?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
unsigned n = 8;
unsigned low8bits = n & 0xFF;
```

Note a few things:

1. For bitwise operations, always use the `unsigned` types
2. Bits can be extracted from numbers using binary masking with the `&` operator
3. To access the low 8 bits the mask is `0xFF` because in binary it has its low 8 bits turned on and the rest 0
4. The low 8 bits of the number 8 are... 8 (think about it for a moment)

---

To access a certain bit of a number, say the `k`th bit:

```
unsigned n = ...;
unsigned kthbit = (1 << k) & n;
```

Now, `kthbit` will be 0 if the `k`th bit of `n` is 0, and some positive number (`2**k`) if the `k`th bit of `n` is 1.

Answer (score 18):

Use bitwise arithmetic to mask off the lowest 8 bits:

```
unsigned char c = (x & 0xFF);
```

To access the nth lowest bit, the equation is `(x & (1 << n))` (n of zero indicates the least significant bit).  A result of zero indicates the bit is clear, and non-zero indicates the bit is set.

Answer (score 9):

The best way is to use the bit logical operator & with the proper value.

So for the lower 8 bits:

```
n & 0xFF; /* 0xFF == all the lower 8 bits set */
```

Or as a general rule:

```
n & ((1<<8)-1) /* generate 0x100 then subtract 1, thus 0xFF */
```

You can combine with the bit shift operator to get a specific bit:

```
(n & (1<<3))>>3; 
  /* will give the value of the 3rd bit - note the >>3 is just to make the value either 0, or 1, not 0 or non-0 */
```

Comment: does the first bit mean '0th' bit or '1st' bit ?

Answer (score 2):

You can test if a particular bit is set in a number using << and &, ie:

`if (num & (1<<3)) ...`

will test if the fourth bit is set or not.

Similarly, you can extract just the lowest 8 bits (as an integer) by using & with a number which only has the lowest 8 bits set, ie `num & 255` or `num & 0xFF` (in hexadecimal).