# how to keep only the lowest 8 bits

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i get the lower 8 bits of int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270307/how-do-i-get-the-lower-8-bits-of-int)

I will create checksum calculator. I do not understand how I can do "Now take the result of 0x247 and keep only the lowest 8 bits which in this example is 0x47" in c. Can you help me ?

Comment: This is homework, obviously.  Use google (hint: masking).

Comment: @JamesAdam: No, use Bing.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth but this is hex value. 0x247

Comment: @GManNickG Why use an extra step to google something? ;-)

Comment: @user1981157: there is no such thing as a hex value, only a hex representation.  The number of apples is not hex or decimal.

Comment: @Oli: heehee "hexordecimal"

Answer (score 3):

Easy, use a bitmask!

You can do this by using the bitwise AND operator.

Here is some code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int number = 0x247, firsteight;

    firsteight = number & 0xFF;

    printf("%x, %x", number, firsteight);

    return 0;
}
```

It works because 0xFF equals 11111111 in binary.

So this is what happens:

```
1001000111 = 0x247
0011111111 = 0xFF
-----------   & (bitwise AND)
0001000111
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an obvious duplicate, but this comment `but this is hex value. 0x247` bothered me. There's lots of ways to represent the same number in a system:

```
int val = 01107;   // 583 in octal
int val2 = 0x247;  // 583 in hex
int val3 = 583;    // 583 in dec
```

but they're all the same value, if I wanted to get the lower 8 bits of any of them you do it the same way, mask the number with a bitwise operator.

```
val3 & 255  = lower 8 bits
val2 & 0xFF = lower 8 bits
val  & 0377 = lower 8 bits
```

Don't think I mean you have to use hex against hex either:

```
(val & 255) == (val2 & 255)
```

is a true statement. That's why, regardless of how the numbers are represented it's usually eaiset to think of it in binary:

```
    0010 0100 0111
  & 0000 1111 1111
  ----------------
    0000 0100 0111  <-- only the last 8 bits are kept
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only last 8 bits from a int value, do `&` with `0xFF`.

```
int a = 0x247;
int b = 0;
b = a & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bitwise operators. For example:
0101010011010001 & 0000000011111111
equals to 11010001.